# Linux/POSIX: timer_settime - Unable to disarm timer from within the timer generated thread

Tags: c, linux, timer

I am trying to disarm a timer but unable to. Below is the snippet for the handler that will be called by glibc ( supposedly in a separate thread context). The thread invokes disarm_timer ( which eventually calls timer_settime). However, it fails with INVALID ARGUMENT set a errno. If i call timer_settime from the handler directly, then it works fine. What could be the problem ? Re-arming time works fine.

```
timer_t timerid;

static void t_thread(union sigval sig)
 {
     if (disarm_timer(timerid) < 0) {
         printf("Bad\n");
     } else {
         printf("Done\n");
     } 
     sleep(10);
     (void)rearm_timer(timerid, 2, 0);
 }

int disarm_timer(timer_t timerid)
 {
     struct itimerspec time_spec; 
     time_spec.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
     time_spec.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;

     if (timer_settime(timerid, 0, &time_spec, NULL) < 0) {
         return -1;
     }
     return 0;
 }

 int rearm_timer(timer_t timerid, time_t tv_sec, long tv_nsec)
 {
     struct itimerspec time_spec;

     if (!timerid) {
         return -1;
     }

     time_spec.it_value.tv_sec = tv_sec;
     time_spec.it_value.tv_nsec = tv_nsec;

     time_spec.it_interval.tv_sec = tv_sec;
     time_spec.it_interval.tv_nsec = tv_nsec;

     if (timer_settime(timerid, 0, &time_spec, NULL) < 0) {
         return -1;
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: It seems you forgot to include the [mcve]. Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Try to initialize the `time_spec` structure, like `struct itimerspec time_spec = { { 0, 0 }, { 0, 0 } };`. Otherwise the `it_interval` structure will contain *indeterminate* (seemingly random/garbage) data.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Indeed.  `disarm_time()` fails to set the `it_interval` values, and POSIX specifies failure with `errno` set to `EINVAL` for "A value structure specified a nanosecond value less than zero or greater than or equal to 1000 million."

Comment: Oh yes!! Sorry!! That was stupid. Thanks for pointing that out. I wasn't initialising the itimerspec struct

Comment: Where did you create the timer ([see `timer_create`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_create.2.html))? Where was `timerid` initialized?